# Ruby: Capybara find() Element not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, capybara

def perform_search

```
fill_in 'q', :with => @skillset
fill_in 'l', :with => @region
find('#fj').click
find("#refineresults", text: "date").click_link
sleep(1)
end
```

Source: https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter/blob/master/scraper.rb

Trying to get indeed.com to sort by date instead of relevance by clicking on the date hyperlink. Can anyone point me to where i'm going wrong with the 4th line in the code?

Comment: What does the HTML look like for what you are trying to click?

Comment: too big to copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click_link` takes parameters to identify the link it's going to click on.  To click on the "date" link in the div with id of refineresults you would do

```
find("#refineresults").click_link("date")
```

If you wanted to find the element manually rather than using click_link you would do

```
find("#refineresults a", text: "date").click
```

although I think the previous solution is clearer as to what you're actually doing

Note: In the future when posting questions, post the actual error your code is producing, it will make it much easier for people to help you

Comment: @user3787179 Is that the error from running the first option in my answer (because it doesn't make any sense as the error from any of your original lines of code)?  If so then you're not on a page that has a "date" link in the refineresults div - check  `page.html` to confirm

Comment: worked great, could you tell me though why put a space and an 'a' after #refineresults ?

Comment: Not sure, i'm sorry. I deleted the comment, your code works.

Comment: @user3787179 In `find("#refineresults a", text: "date").click`   the `#refineresults a` is a CSS selector that says find an 'a' element that is a descendant (the space - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) of an element with id of refineresults.  The text: "date" then says that the found 'a' element has to contain the text "date" - and then click it.  The first option finds the element with id of refineresults then scopes the search for a link to inside that element  - just two ways of getting the same result